# What settings can be changed in android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS or android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS?

Tags: android, permissions, gps, settings, android-wifi

I am completely sure that GPS settings can not be changed programmatically but wifi can be changed by this permission android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE or this adb shell code:

> adb shell "svc wifi enable"

i can turn wifi on. but it needs root permission. what settings can be change by android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS or android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS without needing to be rooted ?

Answer (score 0):

To change the WI-FI state you can add the below permission. Based on the Android version these permissions may vary.

android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS

android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 

wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true); or 

wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```